# Transforming a Pandas timeseries dataframe to a 3D array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray, datetimeindex

I have a timeindexed dataframe with two columns "USER_ID" and "Daily_BALANCE". The dataframe shows the daily balance of users for the month of April 2018 (so 30 observations for each user). I need to generate from that dataframe a 3D numpy array with shape(N (Nb of Users in the dataframe), 30 (daily date), 1 (Balance)) holding the corresponding values. Can anyone help me a code for doing this. for example if we have a 100 users in the dataframe I get an array with the shape(100,30,1) an equivelance of a 100 2D arrays with 30 rows and one column each.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: When you have 100 users and 30 days, you will have 30 balance values for each day for each user, so the shape of your 3D array will be (100, 30, 30). Correct?

Comment: In a situation like this I would highly recommend to create a [dataframe with multi-level index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) instead of a 3D numpy array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you would want to keep only the daily balance values in your final 3D array where to retrieve the balance of the `ith` user of the `jth` day, you would do `arr[i-1, j-1, 0]`.

If that is true, then you first need to sort your dataframe by `USER_ID` and `DATE` and then get the numpy array and finaly `reshape` it

```
n_users = len(df.USER_ID.unique())
n_days = len(df.DATE.unique())

arr = df.sort_values(by=['USER_ID', 'DATE'])['Daily_BALANCE'].values.reshape(n_users, n_days, 1)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I didn't know of the reshape function thanks a lot for the info :)